# Create windows shortcut with python to "Program Files"

Tags: python, python-3.x, win32com, python-winshell

Using below code I'm able to create shortcuts.

The problem is when I try to create a shortcut that lead to "**Program Files**". The resulting shortcut will always end up having Target set to "**Program Files (x86)**".

```
import os

import pythoncom
from win32com.shell import shell

shortcut = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(
    shell.CLSID_ShellLink,
    None,
    pythoncom.CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    shell.IID_IShellLink
)
path = "C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe"
shortcut.SetPath(path)
shortcut.SetIconLocation(path, 0)

persist_file = shortcut.QueryInterface(pythoncom.IID_IPersistFile)
persist_file.Save(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "conEmu.lnk"), 0))
```

Even tough I'm setting path to:
**C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe**

Shortcut for some reason has:
**C:\Program Files (x86)\ConEmu\ConEmu64.exe**

I've also tried:

```
shell = Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut(path)
shortcut.Targetpath = target
```

Same result.